# What happens if a race that naturally has claws picks a class that gives them?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, races, natural-weapon

Okay let’s take [cat folk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-catfolk) for example they have an alternate racial trait called cats claws which give a 1d4 claw attack. Then take a look at [abyssal bloodline bloodrager](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/bloodrager-bloodlines/paizo-bloodrager-bloodlines/abyssal) and I just realized how awkward that is to say. Anyways the bloodrager gives a a claw attack that deals 1d6 for medium creatures from the get go. So that begs the question which source of claws wins? Granted these are just examples that I noticed first there’s probably other ones out there that I’m not aware of.

Comment: Yep it’s a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The abyssal bloodline claws are not "always on", so if you are not actively using your bloodline claws, there is no issue: you use your racial set.

When you *are* using the bloodline claws; they override the racial ones, effectively increasing your claw damage from d4 to d6.

This is different when you have more than 2 pair of arms, one of which has natural claws. In that case; the class claws apply to non-clawed arms, indeed granting more attacks

Comment: "When you are using the bloodline claws; they override the racial ones" Nitpicking: you take the most advantageous set of claws, they do not "override" it. So if you were to get a natural attack with a lower hit dice than one you already possess, you'd use the hit dice you already had.